# How to place configuration files inside pods?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

For example I want to place an application configuration file inside:

```
/opt/webserver/my_application/config/my_config_file.xml
```

I create a ConfigMap from file and then place it in a volume like:

```
/opt/persistentData/
```

The idea is to run afterwards an script that does something like:

```
cp /opt/persistentData/my_config_file.xml  /opt/webserver/my_application/config/
```

But it could be any startup.sh script that does needed actions.

How do I run this command/script? (during Pod initialization before Tomcat startup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first try if this works.

```
  spec:
    containers:
    - volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /opt/webserver/my_application/config/my_config_file.xml
        name: config
        subPath: my_config_file.xml
    volumes:
    - configMap:
        items:
        - key: KEY_OF_THE_CONFIG
          path: my_config_file.xml
        name: config
      name: YOUR_CONFIGMAP_NAME
```

If not, add an [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to copy the file.

```
spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: copy-config
    image: busybox
    command: ['sh', '-c', '/bin/cp /opt/persistentData/my_config_file.xml  /opt/webserver/my_application/config/']
```

Comment: While your solution might work for someone else, it did not work for me, the file gets mounted but the whole folder gets overwritten even if subPath is used. That is way I want to use a script (or an InitContainer I guess) to solve the problem.

Comment: I guess this is the best solution even if it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about mounting the ConfigMap where you actually want it instead of copying over?

**update:**

The init container @ccshih mentioned should do, but one can try other options too:

1. Build a custom image modyfying the base one, using a Docker recipe. The example below takes a java+tomcat7 openshift image, adds an additional folder to the app classpath, so you can mount your ConfigMap to /mnt/config without overwriting anything, keeping both folders available.

.

```
FROM openshift/webserver31-tomcat7-openshift:1.2-6
# add classpaths to config
RUN sed -i 's/shared.loader=/shared.loader=\/mnt\/config/' 
/opt/webserver/conf/catalina.properties
```

2. Change the ENTRYPOINT of the application, either by modifying the image, or by the DeploymentConfig hooks, see: https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/deployments/deployment_strategies.html#pod-based-lifecycle-hook
   With the hooks one just needs to remember to call the original entrypoint or launch script after all the custom stuff is done.

.

```
spec:
  containers:
    -
    name: my-app
    image: 'image'
    command:
      - /bin/sh
    args:
      - '-c'
      - cp /wherever/you/have/your-config.xml /wherever/you/want/it/ && /opt/webserver/bin/launch.sh
```

Comment: I am not able to mount a file only, If i mount the file, the whole folder gets overwritten, even if I do:

volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/webserver/webapps/app/config/file.xml
              subPath: file.xml. But anyway, the question is how to do it with a script.

Comment: Basically I have the same problem like this guy (no good solution yet) https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50345